# Jquery like effects for objective c iOS apps

Tags: jquery, objective-c, api, animation, user-interface

I was wondering if there was a library or something built in to objective c that allows smooth animations and such like jquery provides.

I am not asking how to use jquery with objective c, as I know they are two languages. What I am asking is if there is something written in objective c that is like jquery with the animations and such.

If there is not, could someone point me in the right directions to start building something like that for objective c from scratch.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Animation guide for views:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Here's a great tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial

You can do some cool stuff, like fading a view out then in:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     self.view.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     // Wait one second and then fade in the view
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                           delay: 1.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.view.alpha = 1.0;
                                      }
                                      completion:nil];
                 }];
```